# SharePoint Basic: Document library to list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

User creates new document in document library eg: excel 1 , Excel 2,... I need to merge all spreadsheet together from document library to custom list.. Any Idea??

Comment: Define "Merge": Open all excel and create a new one with all sheets ? Define "To Custom List": On custom list you can't upload document only on document library, maybe you want to attach the new excel to item ? You can create a standard exe or a sharepoint Job ? The sharepoint is 2013 or 2010 ? Is online or on-primese ? I think you must explain better your question. However try to merge excels through [ClosedXml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) and upload (on document lib) with client object model.

Comment: @Max It's sharepoint 2013.. User 1 creates and uploads his/her spreadsheet to doc library.. and same process for User 2 and so on. When Administrator logged-in he/she can able see all together in single speardsheet or in a webpart.. Need to show total revenue by combing all users spreadsheet.. If its possible to add all spreadsheet items into a custom list.. Its easy to show in graph or for better UI.